# UIImagePickerController is crashing on iOS5 but working fine on iOS6+

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

My following code is working fine on iOS6+ but its crashing on iOS5 every **3rd time**, yes its working fine 2 time and crashing on 3rd. I am not doing anything fancy just tapping same button again and again. A button that call this method which contains following line of code.

```
self.imagePopover = nil;
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
UIPopoverController *imagePop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[imagePop presentPopoverFromRect:self.profileImageButton.frame inView:self.profileImageButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.imagePopover = imagePop;
```

And and in

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
     picker.delegate = nil;
     [self.imagePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

And following is what it says in consol for crash

```
*** -[PLUISavedPhotosAlbumViewController hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6dbd390
```

Some time `PLUISavedPhotosAlbumViewController` is replaced by `UIImagePickerController` but formate of log is same `Something` hash]: message sent to deallocated instance `something`. And it crashes on following line from first piece of code

```
 [imagePop presentPopoverFromRect:self.profileImageButton.frame inView:self.profileImageButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you post your error message that you receive thanks

Comment: What do you mean it gets replaced by UIImagePickerController sometimes?

Comment: @SorinCioban mean that in error message some time it also says *** -[UIImagePickerController hash]: message sent to deallocated instance - without changing any code.